# WPF ContentPresenter bound to a collection

Tags: wpf, data-binding, contentpresenter

I have a collection of string.

I want to create an image out of each of the strings using a converter.

I tried binding the collection to a `ContentPresenter`, but I don't know what do to when binding to a collection since I don't know how many items are in the collection.

I don't want to put it in a container such as `ListBox`, I want the images to be in an existing `Grid`...

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you want to use ItemsContol such as the ListBox? ItemsControls provide the easies and most natural way to display collections? Moreover you will not have to use converter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place images in ItemsControl and define ItemsPanel template to layout images as u like.

Read this article for [details](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/CustomListBoxLayoutInWPF.aspx?display=Print).

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to do.

Thank you!